# Where to get Gnome Night Light source code?

Tags: gnome, dconf, source-code, mutter, night-light

I had thought of asking this question on Stackoverflow but there all the "Night Light" references are for Windows 10 Night Light. Too bad Microsoft and Gnome Developers didn't draw straws for who would call their application "Blueshift" or whatever.

Preamble aside... How do I get source code for Night Light (Gnome version)? Would source code for Mutter and dconf / gsettings also be needed?

I understand there are different versions 3.34.1, 3.35.1 and 3.36 beta:

- [GNOME's Mutter 3.35.1 Fixes The Night Light Mode On Wayland](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GNOME-Mutter-3.35.1-Released)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the other answer just provided the source code for the UI which is not very helpful, here is the actual logic if someone else is searching for this:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/tree/master/plugins/color

I found it by searching for relevant commits on the GNOME Gitlab.

Comment: Fascinating development is over 10 years long.

Comment: The folder also contains other color management features, I don't think that Night Light has been around for that long.

Answer (score 2):

considering Ubuntu 18.04

I think its here for Ubuntu 18.04 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-control-center/

some of the content of `apt show gnome-control-center`

```
APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
Description: utilities to configure the GNOME desktop
 This package contains configuration applets for the GNOME desktop,
 allowing to set accessibility configuration, desktop fonts, keyboard
 and mouse properties, sound setup, desktop theme and background, user
 interface properties, screen resolution, and other GNOME parameters.
```

http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-control-center/

[image]

you can check your gnome-shell version and then download that version number from above link.. for example if you want for 3.34 download that version number.

[image]

Comment: Or get it from [GNOME's GitHub page](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-control-center/tree/master/panels/display)

Comment: Thanks for the lead to follow up on. Interesting lots of files in the link are 5 years old and a couple are 7 years old. Plus it includes support for 32 bit processors. I wonder if something from Gnome would be more concise than something from Ubuntu?

Comment: @Kulfy We posted at same time.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix On GNOME's GitHub page last commit for Night light was done 3 months ago. Moreover the link PRATAP provided is of Ubuntu's  pool of archives. It hosts all the packages released for any Ubuntu version till now unless that version reached its respective EOL
.

Comment: @Kulfy Thanks for the clarification. The "control center" seems focused on user interface if I'm right. In that case there must be more code for background processing tasks pertaining to night light. For example reading the dconf database to see if it is time to turn light on or off. How to process differently if Wayland or Xorg are controlling the screens would be there too I guess.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yeah but under the hood I expect some C code to work. I think in this particular case [this C file](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-control-center/blob/master/panels/display/cc-night-light-page.c) is responsible. I haven't gone through the code so I'm not sure about XOrg and Wayland. Also, since dconf depends on GLib and the C code I linked is include glib's header file and using thereafter. So the code may work without dconf. I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Kulfy It might be worthwhile studying some Night Light extensions to see what code they had to modify. It might not provide all the answers but could give lots of clues.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Sounds reasonable :)